# Reconnect asio connection when the server is alive

Tags: c++, tcp, go, boost-asio

I want to keep an asio connection responsive, that I mean to check the server every second till it become alive and then send and receive. Here is my code

---irunnable.h---

```
#ifndef IRUNNABLE_H
#define IRUNNABLE_H

#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

class IRunnable
{
public:
    IRunnable(): mThread(nullptr) {
        mRunning.store(false);
    }

    virtual ~IRunnable() {
        if (mRunning.load())
            Stop();
        delete mThread;
    }


    virtual void Start() {
        mRunning.store(true);
        mThread = new std::thread(&IRunnable::Run, this);
    }

    virtual void Stop() {
        mRunning.store(false);
        if (mThread && mThread->joinable())
            mThread->join();
    }

    virtual bool IsRunning() {return mRunning.load();}

protected:
    virtual void Run() = 0;

    std::atomic<bool> mRunning;

private:
    std::thread *mThread;
};

#endif // IRUNNABLE_H
```

---mytcpconnection.h---

```
#ifndef MYTCPCONNECTION_H
#define MYTCPCONNECTION_H

#include <asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include "irunnable.h"


class MyTCPConnection : public IRunnable
{
public:
    MyTCPConnection(const std::string &ip, const std::string &port);

    ~MyTCPConnection();

    void Stop();

    void Write(const std::string &msg);

    void Connect();
protected:
    void Run();

private:
    void readHeader();

private:
    std::string mIP;
    std::string mPort;
    asio::io_service mIOService;
    asio::ip::tcp::socket mSocket;
};

#endif // MYTCPCONNECTION_H
```

---mytcpconnection.cpp

```
#include "mytcpconnection.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <asio/connect.hpp>
#include <asio/write.hpp>
#include <asio/read.hpp>

MyTCPConnection::MyTCPConnection(const std::string &ip, const std::string &port):
    mIP(ip),
    mPort(port),
    mSocket(mIOService)
{
    Connect();
}

MyTCPConnection::~MyTCPConnection()
{
    Stop();
}

void MyTCPConnection::Stop()
{
    mIOService.stop();
    mSocket.close();
    IRunnable::Stop();
}

void MyTCPConnection::Write(const std::string &msg)
{
    asio::async_write(mSocket,
                    asio::buffer(msg.c_str(),
                                msg.length()),
                    [this, msg](std::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout <<  msg << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            mSocket.close();
        }
    });
}



void MyTCPConnection::Run()
{

    while (mRunning.load()) {
        sleep(1);
//        Connect();
        std::cout << "before run\n";
        mIOService.run();
        std::cout << "after run\n";
    }

}

void MyTCPConnection::Connect()
{
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(mIOService);
    asio::async_connect(mSocket, resolver.resolve({mIP, mPort}),
                        [this](std::error_code ec, asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "readHeader called\n";
            readHeader();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "can not connect\n";
            mSocket.close();
            mIOService.reset();
            std::cout << "after stopping io_service\n";
        }
    });
}

void MyTCPConnection::readHeader()
{
    const int header_length = 16;
    std::shared_ptr<char> msg(new char[header_length]{0},
        [](char *c) {
            delete[] c;
    });
    asio::async_read(mSocket,
                    asio::buffer(msg.get(), header_length),
                    [this, msg](std::error_code ec, std::size_t s/*length*/)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "Message read " << s << std::endl;
            readHeader();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "closing socket\n";
            mSocket.close();
            mIOService.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

---main.cpp---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mytcpconnection.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyTCPConnection conn("127.0.0.1", "12345");
    conn.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        conn.Write("Hello server");

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---server.go---

```
package main

import (
        "time"
        "fmt"
        "net"
)

func handle_conn(conn net.Conn) {
    b := make([]byte, 1028)
    for {
        n, err:= conn.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(string(b[:n]))
        _, _ = conn.Write([]byte("hellohellohello1"))
        time.Sleep(time.Second*1)
    }
}

func main() {
        ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":12345")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Println("server started")
        for {
                conn, err := ln.Accept()
        fmt.Println("connection from", conn.RemoteAddr())
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err.Error())
                        continue
                }
                go handle_conn(conn)
        }
}
```

In this form, the client connects to the server (when the server is running) and keeps reading and writing. If I move the Connect() method in the mytcpconnection constructor to the Run() function (where it is commented now), the connection is not able to connect to the server.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: At a cursory glance: there are thread safety violations for the `socket` which may result in undefined behavior; the `async_write()` operation fails to meet the requirement that the underlying buffer will remain valid until the completion handler is invoked; the `stop()` and `reset()` flow can result in the socket connecting then disconnecting every second; and even with a clean `reset()`, enqueued completion handlers may force disconnections. Is the application protocol full-duplex? Will the connection be concurrently accessed by multiple threads (including the one running the `io_service`)?

Comment: I agree with you that the async_write is not thread safe. I first want to solve the above problem then will deal with thread safety. The connection will be duplex for the smpp protocol.

Comment: The lack of thread safety and buffer management may result in undefined behavior being invoked.  It seems like a futile effort and test of patience to try to solve a problem in the presence of undefined behavior (including having it not connect).  I will try to find some time to provide a solution to the above issues, but resolving the above identified issues _should_ fix the problem.

Comment: Where your `MyTCPConnection::Run()` is actually called?

Comment: @PSIAlt: In Start() of the IRunnable, which is the parent of MyTCPConnection (conn.Start() in the main function)